# Did I damage my RAM?

Tags: esd

I recently purchased Corsair Dominator Platinum DDR4 RAM , and for some reason I decided to take it out of the box and I touched it without anti static protection of any kind . I didn't touch the RAM connectors, but only the machined aluminium heat sinks covering it. Did I damage the RAM with ESD?

Comment: What makes you think it is damaged? Is it malfunctioning?

Comment: touching without anti static protection does not damage RAM in most cases. If you're not sure, insert the RAM in your PC and do a memory test http://www.memtest.org/

Comment: Does it function?  ESD damage to electronics cannot be seen, so if you damaged your memory, the only way you would know is if the memory didn't function.  In the future don't touch electronics without being grounded.

Answer (score 2):

More than likely, probably not. ESD damage is actually pretty rare to an extent where it causes noticeable damage to components. Your RAM should be completely fine

Answer (score -1):

Did you get a shock? No? Was no electro-static disharge then. Otherwise most likely yes.

Comment: ESD could have still occurred at a level high enough to damage electronics even though no shock was felt.

Comment: Being "shocked" isn't a requirement for ESD damage to electronics......